# How to simplify these code?(if the first few elements in two nested lists are the same, count+1)

Tags: python

I have two nested lists:

```
A=[[a,1,A],[a,2,A],[a,1,A],[b,1,B],[a,1,A]]

B=[[a,1,A],[a,2,A],[b,1,B]]
```

What I want is to count how many elements in A is equal to B(B is like a index), and append B

at the end we need to get

```
C=[[[a,1,A,3],[a,2,A,1],[b,1,B,1]]]
```

the last element is the count of same stuff in both A and B

my code:

```
for i in range(len(index)):
    index[i].append(0)
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if index[i][0]==df[j][0] and index[i][1]==df[j][1] and index[i][2]==df[j][2]:
            index[i][3]+=1
return
```

but it  seems very rare when there are lots of elements in `A[i]`(we cannot use too much `and`)

how can we make it easier to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `collections.Counter` here for an `O(n)` solution:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter(map(tuple, A))
print(cnt)
#Counter({('a', 1, 'A'): 3, ('a', 2, 'A'): 1, ('b', 1, 'B'): 1})
```

I mapped the values in A to a `tuple` because you need a hashable type for `Counter`.

Now that you have the counts, just look up and append the count for each value in `B`:

```
C = [b + [cnt.get(tuple(b), 0)] for b in B]
print(C)
#[['a', 1, 'A', 3], ['a', 2, 'A', 1], ['b', 1, 'B', 1]]
```

---

Behind the scenes, `collections.Counter` is doing roughly the following:

```
cnt = {}
for a in (tuple(a) for a in A):
    if a not in cnt:
        cnt[a] = 0
    cnt[a] += 1
```

So as you can see, with only one pass through list `A`, you have the counts for all values in `A`. By pre-computing the counts ahead of time, you are able to do subsequent lookups (the values in `B`) in constant time `O(1)`.

Contrast this with other solutions which are of the form:

```
for b in B:
    for a in A:
        if a == b:
            # increment a counter
```

These are inefficient because you are looping through all the values in `A` for each value in `B`. If the lengths of these lists are small you won't notice a difference, but there will be dramatic differences as the size of your data grows.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to compare each item of the list, you can use == on whole lists:

```
for i in range(len(index)):
    counter = 0
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if index[i] == df[j]:
            counter += 1
    index[i].append(counter)
```

Comment: so what should I do if I just want to compare the first several rows? exp: A,B have 100 rows and I want to compare the first 50 of them

Comment: What do you mean by rows, the number of items in the sub-list? You could do this: `index[i][0:50] == df[j][0:50]`

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in `.count` method that works well for this

```
c = []

for item in (b):
    num = a.count(b) 
    item.append(num)
    c.append(item)

print(c)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 nest_list.py
> [['a', 1, 'A', 0], ['a', 2, 'A', 0], ['b', 1, 'B', 0]]
> ```

Comment: This is highly inefficient.

Comment: what makes you say this ?

Comment: not everyone wants to use external modules,  when you can do the same task with 3 lines and no importing

Comment: 1) `count` will traverse the entire list each iteration. 2) `collections.Counter` is not an "external" module 3) You can also build  your own `O(n)` solution without any imports. 4) The number of lines is irrelevant

Comment: @pault I'm creating a solution relative to OP level, im assuming using an import and map is out of the context of what someone with 70 rep understand and deploy immediately

Comment: @pault also the desired output is in form of a nested list, not a dictionary and you are mapping them to a tuple there are many extra steps that someone may not want to go through, I agree for higher level an `0(n)` solution is better but here I don't believe so

Comment: Whatever the level of the programming (which you shouldn't assume based on rep), you should still provide best practices. Since your brought it up, your output is a list of strings which is not what OP wanted. If you re-read my solution, you'll see that `C` is actually in the form that OP wants.

Comment: @pault I just noticed I used a string for the output I don't know why i did that fixing it now

Comment: @pault Updated for list output, but there is a confliction amongst you higher ups, it seems one time you guys tell me to respond in a manner that OP can understand, and then another one of you will say that my response is using elements out of scope of OP

Comment: @pault I am not disagree'ing with the fact a `0(n)` solution is better its just the context of answering on this site has been back and forth between highest level possible and tailor to OP